# How to manage Add and Edit data in One screen in React native (functional component)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am manage Add and Edit data in One screen. How to manage pass param (Edit) and Add data that time not use param.

When i press Create post button then apps is go to error bcz param is undefined.

So, How to manage both Add and Edit (With param and without param).

Thanks

Comment: add more detail or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way
You can pass param in navigation like below

```
navigate.navigate('Employee', data: objectOfYourEmployeeData)
```

If your add/Edit screen you can check access data value as below

```
const {route} = props;
const {objectOfYourEmployeeData} = route.params;
```

and then set value in your required field by checking objectOfYourEmployeeData is null or not

If objectOfYourEmployeeData is not null it means you want to Edit data and set value by extract objectOfYourEmployeeData If objectOfYourEmployeeData is null or undefined it
means you are want to add data

```
const [name, setName] = useState(objectOfYourEmployeeData?.name || '' );
const [email, setEmail] = useState(objectOfYourEmployeeData?.email || '');
```

Comment: What is use of ? mark in javascript?

Comment: @Vicky it is check null or undefined so your application will not crash if you got any value null or undefined in javascript or typescript

Comment: Thanks @iOS Team